# How do I pass HTML radio button value to a PHP variable using Javascript and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, radio-button

I am trying to pass the user's checked HTML radio button value to a PHP variable using Jquery/Javascript and Ajax.

The following is a simplified version of the HTML/Javascript (without error checking, etc.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" id="smallBtn" value="1"/>
<input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" id="smallBtn" value="2"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[name=bus_plan]").on('change', function(){
    var $postID = $('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
    $postID = "="+$postID;
    });
    $.ajax ({
       type: "GET",
       url: "localhost/ajax/product-group.php",
       data: {"postID" : $postID }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is a simplified version of the PHP program (localhost/ajax/product-group.php):

```
<?php
  $postid = $_GET['postID']; 
  echo "The PostID is ".$postid;
?>
```

This is running on a MAMP stack.

The Javascript works up until the $.ajax call and then PHP program (localhost/ajax/product-group.php) is never "called".

Any advice or help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$("input[name=bus_plan]").on('change', function(){
   var $postID = $('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
   $postID = "="+$postID;
});

$.ajax ({
   type: "GET",
   url: "localhost/ajax/product-group.php",
   data: {"postID" : $postID }
});
```

With:

```
$("input[name=bus_plan]").on('change', function(){
    var $postID = $('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
    $postID = "="+$postID;
    $.ajax ({
       type: "GET",
       url: "localhost/ajax/product-group.php",
       data: {"postID" : $postID }
    });
});
```

or with your code make ajax **async** by adding **async = false** in options

With your code you dont know when ajax gets called before radio button gets changed or after since its **asynchronous**, adding **async=false** as ajax option you will make sure that it will execute synchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can't really see the issue until you properly indent the code:

```
$("input[name=bus_plan]").on('change', function() {
    var $postID = $('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
    $postID = "="+$postID;
});
$.ajax ({
   type: "GET",
   url: "localhost/ajax/product-group.php",
   data: {"postID" : $postID }
});
```

Few issues:

1. Your `$postID` is local to the change handler
2. `$.ajax()` runs immediately.
3. The URL is missing `http://` scheme.

You should move the `$.ajax()` call inside as well, so that it only runs when something changes:

```
$("input[name=bus_plan]").on('change', function() {
    var $postID = "=" + $('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
    $.ajax ({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost/ajax/product-group.php",
       data: {"postID" : $postID }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jack and @GGio for your replies.  By adding moving the ajax call and adding ajax error handling, ajax is working correctly.  However the called php program doesn't seem to work as the echo statements never display.  (They do it's when run stand-alone).  So now the code reads: